# How can I use index method to see if one word matches user input in hangman?

Tags: python

I am designing a hangman game for the final project of our club, and there is a problem on determining whether the letter the user inputs matches the one in the original word (for example: if the user inputs `e` in the second blank of t_n_orflow, which is the word tensorflow, I need to see if the user inputs e.)

 However, for a more exciting game experience, I used random to randomly put blanks in the word, and there may be multiple blanks present at different positions of the word each time. Then when I try to write an if block to decide whether the user has input the wrong letter, the codes start to go wrong.

 At first I used `if letter in select` to see if the letter is in the word selected. However, some words have multiple same letters and the program made a wrong decision.

Then I used the index method to find the index of blank in the word. For example, the index of the first blank in `t_n_orflow` is 2, and I use the index to find the letter in `select`, which is the correct one. However, since there are multiple blanks, the letter user inputs filled both blanks.

 So is there any other way to solve the problem, which means the if block will determine whether the user input is correct once at a time? (For example, if the user inputs e in t_n_orflow, the program will see if the user inputs `e` then decide whether the user inputs `s`.

This is the main block which goes wrong.

```
if difficulty==1:
        x = ''.join(i if random.randint(0, 5) else '_' for i in prog_word)
        print("The word you need to guess is {}".format(x))
        # print(res)
        while True:
            letter=input("Please input letters by order")
            res=x.index(blank)
            ans=select[res]
            if letter == ans: #TODO: use index method
                print("Hangman is safe. You can go on")
                x=x.replace('_',letter)
                print(x)
                if x==select:
                    print("You won.")
                    break
            else:
                print("Uh oh, wrong answer.")
                attempt+=1
                print("Your current attempt is {}".format(attempt))
```

In this code, `select` is the correct word, and `res` is the index of the blank, in which the program will see whether `ans` corresponds to `select`.

Comment: You shouldn't use replace, which replaces all _ . You already know the index/indices of the letters (which is 1, not 2 in your example). Maybe store the word as a list of letters, then it is easier to replace letters with a specific index.

Comment: instead of `replace` try this `x=x[:res] + ans + x[res+1:]` but that will only work if the guessed letter takes up only one blank,as @Stefan said, you should try and implement a better way to find indices of guessed letter in correct word that will also find and return multiple indices in case it takes up more than one blanks and then replace those indices. Also you should implement a check for invalid inputs from user right now it just crashes if it dont find the guessed letter in the correct word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code demonstrates a simple way, you only need to compare each input character to match the answer in `answers`.

```py
>>> from random import sample
>>> word = 'Beautiful'
>>> indexes = sorted(sample(range(len(word)), 3))
>>> question = ''.join('_' if i in indexes else word[i] for i in range(len(word)))
>>> answers = [word[i] for i in indexes]
>>> question
'B_a__iful'
>>> answers
['e', 'u', 't']
```

Comment: Then except using ``replace`` is there any way to fill the blanks with the correct letter user has input each time (``replace`` will replace all the blanks inside)

Comment: Find next `index` in `indexes`,  `question = word[:index]+question[index:]`